# Auto-connect to iPhone hotspot

Tags: iphone, ios, network, wifi, tethering

My iPhone Wi-Fi hotspot (first one in the screenshot) is shown with a different icon from any other hotspots (Android, broadband etc).

[image]

This doesn't bother me except I need to manually re-connect my Mac to the hotspot whenever it's restarted/woke up from sleep, instead of it auto-connecting like other Wi-Fi hotspots.

Anyway to get my Mac to auto-reconnect?

Specs:

iPhone 6 iOS running iOS 11.2
MacBook Pro running macOS Sierra

Comment: Same appleId on both devices?  If so, you shouldn’t need to connect.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Sytem Preferences>Network>Wi-Fi>Advanced>Wi-Fi and drag the item with hotspot name to the top.  This will prioritize that Wifi network over any other network.

Comment: Does not work in MacOS 10.14